# How to get all subdirectories inside a directory within a jscript running on a local html

Tags: jquery, html, jscript

I want to create a little File-Explorer which shows up all sub-directories of a specific directory inside a local html-file. the user should have the opportunity to select a folder and all sub folders should be listed. To append those tags/directories to my html I am using JQuery. I want to create a function which takes as an argument the path to the directory and gives back the sub-directories in an array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as you don't have an index.html or index.php of any kind in a directory, by default you can browse directories on most if not all file systems.

Comment: You'll need `hta` application to have access to the local file system through  javascript/html